# Get the sum of all collectionViewCells' heights inside a CollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, size, height, uicollectionviewcell

I have a CollectionView created inside CollectionView cell class.

The thing is I can't get the CollectionView that lives inside the first collectionView get the perfect size to fit all cells' sizes if any.

[image]

First level comments Line is the First CollectionView Cell, enclosing the second level comments(contentView is blue and the collectionView holding the cells is red)

I am using constraints to set the second collectionView height. It's basically fixed now.

I know how to make the comments cells have dynamic height, but how can I make the second collectionView have dynamic height to fit all cells if any?

Possible solution, doing something with:

```
for cell in collectionView.visibleCells as! [MyCellClass] {
   let sumOfAllCells += cell.frame.height 

}
```

Comment: Why nesting two collection views?

Comment: Looked the fastest way to implement. Have a better sugguestion?

Comment: The easiest and I think even better solution would be just use a single collection view with two kind of cells, then just arrange your data source to contain both first and second level comments

Comment: Also, sizing a collection view to show all cells makes the usage of collection view pointless because it will not recycle any cell

Comment: I can't figure out how to dequeue two different cells. Can you provide an example, an article or a post?

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio I managed to use two kind of cells like you said and, check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56525623/multiple-cells-for-comments-and-reply-in-a-collectionview Now I only have to sort comments. Thanks man for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var height: CGFloat = 0
collectionView.visibleCells.forEach({ height += $0.bounds.height })
```

Comment: Your code works fine but for whatever reason it don't work. I am using constraints to set the collectionView's height so I set it to your height var. I guess I somehow have to call your code before setting constraints and after populating collection view with cells

Comment: @ISS when do you call it, and what exactly don't work ?

Comment: in a sharedInit() func I am setting the constraints. I tried calling it there and at cell index at path and size at index path. At size at index path the value grew to infinite however the size still didn't change

Comment: @Iss you should call it, when the cells are visible

Comment: Is there a func like whenCellVisible() or you mean something like viewDidAppear?

Comment: @ISS viewDidAppear

Comment: It's a CollectionViewCell where I'm trying to do it, so it doesn't have a viewDidAppear method..

Comment: @ISS in this case do it in viewdidlayoutsubviews