# Multiple Cells for Comments and Reply in a CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have two different cells types one is for comments and the other one for replies. I'm trying to render them in the same `collectionView` and then maybe grouping them like so: each comment with a certain id to have under it its replies. However, with any attempt, I failed.

How would you go about it?

```
private var comments = [Comment]()
private var replies = [Reply]()
var items: [Any] = []


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
//        let item = items[indexPath.item]

        var item = items[indexPath.item]

        if item is Comment.Type  {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CommentCell.cellId, for: indexPath) as! CommentCell
            cell.comment = items[indexPath.item] as? Comment
            print(item)
            return cell


        } else {
                    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: RepliesCell.cellId, for: indexPath) as! RepliesCell
            cell.reply = items[indexPath.item] as? Reply

                    return cell

        }



    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let item = items[indexPath.item]

        if item is CommentCell.Type {

            let dummyCell = CommentCell(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 50))
            dummyCell.comment = items[indexPath.item] as? Comment
            dummyCell.layoutIfNeeded()

            let targetSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 250)
            let estimatedSize = dummyCell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize)
            let height = max(40 + 8 + 8, estimatedSize.height)

            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: height)
        } else {
            let dummyCell = RepliesCell(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 50))
            dummyCell.reply = items[indexPath.item] as? Reply
            dummyCell.layoutIfNeeded()

            let targetSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 250)
            let estimatedSize = dummyCell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize)
            let height = max(40 + 8 + 8, estimatedSize.height)

            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: height)
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, every reply has a depency of a comment. If yes, you need to put replies inside a comments model.

Comment: Yes replies are in a node that has the Comment ID value. I already have a model for replies and would like to work with it as it is.

Comment: Then I can't understand what you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: @EmreÖnder render two different uiviewcells types in the same collectionView. I already have a separate model for each, Comment and Reply, and am retreiving data from firebase

Comment: Your code looks correct. It has a check that current item is a reply or comment and then return cell regarding of the type. Please check If It goes into both If and else blocks

Comment: At some point it got me "index out of range" when establishing size for replies and then failed to show the cells I want. It only displays a single cell with placeholder image.

Comment: Can you please share what is inside items object and where you assign it?

Comment: I've got two functions that fetch data from firebase and then append it to Items. Basically it's a collection of Comments and Replies which I plan to sort by grouping.

Comment: Please debug the code and check If items count is the right one when It goes into collectionviews number of cells function

Comment: You were right. Items and Comments and Replies Count are zero, so before I check what kind of item I have in the Items array I must check wether is empty or not.

Comment: After you fetch the data for both arrays, call collectionView.reloadData()

Comment: Am doing it. However, it seems it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Then you need to share where you assign your arrays and how to reload collectionView.

Comment: Your assumptions were right.I was fetching the replies the wrong way. I'll update you with progress soon. Thanks!

Comment: What I really wanted to achieve can be see in my answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best practice solution

Create a Reply model and Comment model which contains Replies object list

```
class Comment {
    var commentId: Int
    var commentText: String
    var replies: [Reply]

    init(commentId: Int, commentText: String, replies: [Reply]) {
        self.commentId = commentId
        self.commentText = commentText
        self.replies = replies
    }
}

class Reply {
    var replyId: Int
    var replyText: String

    init(replyId: Int, replyText: String) {
        self.replyId = replyId
        self.replyText = replyText
    }
}
```

Create a UICollectionReusableView for comment header

```
class CommentHeader: UICollectionReusableView {

    @IBOutlet weak var commentTextLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func configure(with comment: Comment) {
        commentTextLabel.text = comment.commentText
    }

}
```

Create a UICollectionViewCell for reply

```
class ReplyCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var replyTextLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func configure(with reply: Reply) {
        replyTextLabel.text = reply.replyText
    }

}
```

Create a CommentsViewController class which has a UICollectionView and comments data list

Attention that the header and cell are registered into the collection view in the viewDidLoad method

```
class CommentsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var comments: [Comment] = [Comment]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CommentHeader", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "CommentHeaderIdentifier")
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "ReplyCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ReplyCellIdentifier")

        comments = getDummyComments(with: 3)
    }

    func getDummyComments(with count: Int) -> [Comment] {

        var comments = [Comment]()
        for i in 1...count {
            comments.append(Comment(commentId: i, commentText: "Comment \(i)", replies: getDummyReplies(with: i)))
        }
        return comments

    }

    func getDummyReplies(with count: Int) -> [Reply] {
        var replies = [Reply]()
        for i in 1...count {
            replies.append(Reply(replyId: i, replyText: "Reply \(i)"))
        }
        return replies
    }
}
```

And finally set UICollectionView datasource and delegate methods

```
extension CommentsViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    // for cell
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return comments.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return comments[section].replies.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let replyCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ReplyCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! ReplyCell
        replyCell.configure(with: comments[indexPath.section].replies[indexPath.row])
        return replyCell

    }

    // for header
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {

            let commentHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "CommentHeaderIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! CommentHeader

            commentHeader.configure(with: comments[indexPath.section])
            return commentHeader
        }

        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 100) // this height is used for the example, you can use self sizing for height
    }

}

extension CommentsViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 100) // this height is used for the example, you can use self sizing for height

    }

}
```

Let's see the comments screen :)

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. I'll give that a try and come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

correct me if i am wrong, you are trying to make nested cells, and each has a header type thing which is comment just like Facebook, right!

so the thing is, the comment thing will be in the header of each section and the replies will be in the cells. so in this way, the comments will appear at the top of each section, and replies cells acts as the body. you will need numberOfSections delegate for comments and numberOfRows delegate for replies.

Ask me if you don't get it right.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to make nested cells, but I was never thinking to do it with header. I'll give it a try and come back to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: this way you can easily manage your data, i mean, i usually use this approach whenever i encountered this problem. so you should also give it a try. do inform me.

Comment: I can't get it to work. Will you please show me a code sample, and each method I must implement?

Comment: first of all tell me can you make your layout via storyboard?

Comment: for both comment and replies

Comment: Nope. It's all done programmatically for both comments and replies

Comment: I just found an error in my code while fetching Replies from the server. I'll give your suggestion a try again.

Comment: Finally did it. You may check the answer I posted to see what I was looking for. Thanks for your time! You're the man!

Comment: glad to hear... <3

Answer (score 0):

So what I basically did was creating a PostType Class so I can switch through comments and replies types when I had to render a certain cell type.

```
class PostType {
    enum CommentsTypes {
        case PostType
        case Reply
        case Comment
    }

    var type: CommentsTypes {
        get {
            return .PostType
        }
    }
}
```

Subclassed my Comments and Replies classes to PostType just like this:

```
class Comment: PostType {

   ....

    override var type: CommentsTypes {
        return .Comment
    }
}

class Reply: PostType {

    ....

    override var type: CommentsTypes {
        return .Reply
    }
}
```

Then I made an array of PostType to hold comments and replies after fetching them:

```
 var postsTypes: [PostType] = []

 //after fetching comments and replies 
self.postsTypes.append(contentsOf: comments)
self.postsTypes.append(contentsOf: replies)
```

Finally set

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return postsTypes.count
    }
```

and

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let item = indexPath.item
let post = self.postsTypes[item]

switch post.type  {
case .Comment:
    let comment = post as! Comment
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CommentCell.cellId, for: indexPath) as! CommentCell
    cell.comment = comment
    return cell
case .Reply:
    let reply = post as! Reply
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: RepliesCell.cellId, for: indexPath) as! RepliesCell

    cell.reply = reply

    return cell

default:
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
}
```

Works like a charm! So glad I finally found the answer to my question. Thanks everyone for their suggestions.

Comment: Does anyone have a better answer?